# How do I install a privately created extension in a devcontainer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a private VSCode extension.

Is it possible to install and use this VSCode extension in devcontainer?
If possible, I'd like to put it in devcontainer.json or something similar for **automatic** installation.

I have already confirmed that I can install it by following the steps below.

1. copy the private extension at docker image build time
2. start devcontainer by specifying the built docker image.
3. pass the code command in devcontainer to make it available.
4. install the private extension with the code command

Thank you for taking time to answer.

Comment: copy the development directory (the JS files, not the TS files) to the `~/.vscode/extensions` folder in the docker image

Comment: Thank you for your comment. By development directory do you mean the directory that is created when you run `npx yo code` ?

Comment: the directory that has `package.json`